# Как вывести на экран 5 последних записей в таблице бд?

Tags: php, mysql

Как вывести на экран 5 последних записей в таблице бд?

Comment: Плохой вопрос. Во-первых, нужно уточнить, что значит «последних» — есть ли индекс по этому полю или нет, что еще о нем известно. Во-вторых, в каждой СУБД есть свои механизмы для лимитирования выдачи — views, limits, rownum и еще много всякого. Про «вывести на экран» даже говорить ничего не хочется.

Comment: Такое впечатление, что Влад - засланный казачок... Специально, чтоб показать народу, как не надо задавать вопросы :) 

Я просмотрел все вопросы этого перца - в лучшем случае они не отмечены никак, в худшем - минусовые :) 

Но, к чести тутошнего народа, местная толерантность зашкаливает :) Приятно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если не сделали этого ранее, соединяемся:

```
mysql_connect($host,$username,$password);
mysql_select_db($db_name);
```

Делаем запрос и выводим(вместо id можно использовать date или любой другой столбец, по которому можно определить очередность):

```
$res = mysql_query('select * from `table_name` where 1 order by `id` desc limit 5');
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)){  
  print(implode('|',$row).'<br />');  
}
```

P.S. Кстати, гуру, а как вывести 5 последних записей, если НЕТ столбца сортировки?
Неужели придется запрашивать количество элементов отдельно?

Comment: Чё? У меня айди сортируеться и через него и выводить !

Comment: Не, Влад, я не тебя спрашиваю. Мне правда интересно. =)
Для тебя - все, что до PS

Comment: Если нет столбца сортировки, нет *последних* записей, все просто)

Comment: да. Но они же как-то выводятся. Если просто вывести звездочкой, они выводятся в КАКОМ-ТО порядке. Причем всегда одинаковом. Вот как его инвертировать?

Comment: Не всегда одинаковом, мускул может новую запись влепить на место ранее удаленной, следующую в конец, т.к. она больше доступного промежутко, а следующую поменьше влепить опять в серединку. Просто смысла в такой сортировке нет, т.к. оно не от записей, а от настроения сервера зависит.

Comment: А knes сори за наезд))) А через while просто перебираем до какого нам нужно места))

Comment: @knes: в MySQL умолчальный порядок (table scan) разумеется, не определен, а на практике зависит еще от движка: для InnoDB будет взят primary key, если он есть, для MyISAM, даже если PK есть, он использован не будет. До тех пор, пока в таблице не было UPDATE/DELETE, порядок table scan совпадает с порядком INSERT'ов в таблицу. Но даже на это полагаться нельзя. И даже напрямую работая с хэндлами инвертировать его нельзя.